# Android: Notification is not vibrating/sounding/flashing light when screen is locked

Tags: android, notifications, push, builder

I use Firebase Messaging Service, to receive Push-Notifications.
Everything is working very well, if my screen is unlocked.

When my screen is locked, i receive the Notification, but my phone is not making any sound, is not vibrating and my light is not flashing.

This is my code to generate the message:

```
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String messageTitle) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setLights(Color.CYAN, 1, 1)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: is it working when screen is on?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for send  notification this work fine

```
 private static final long[] vPattern = new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000};

 public static void sendNotification(Context ctx, NotificationData notificationData) {
        try {
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Integer notifiId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            Intent intent_for_Notification = new Intent();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable(Constants.NOTIFICATION_DATA, notificationData);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
            mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationData.msg));
            mBuilder.setContentText(notificationData.msg);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            intent_for_Notification.putExtras(b);
            intent_for_Notification.setClass(ctx, SplashActivity.class);
            intent_for_Notification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, notifiId, intent_for_Notification, 0);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_196);
            mBuilder.setVibrate(vPattern);
            mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifiId, mBuilder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` in your manifest?

> One legitimate case for using a wake lock might be a background service that needs to grab a wake lock to keep the CPU running to do work while the screen is off. Again, though, this practice should be minimized because of its impact on battery life. - [Android Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

You may try adding `notificationBuilder.setDefault(defaults)` as I do notice some of the phone are not producing any sound even you have set `.setSound(defaultSoundUri)`.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setLights(Color.CYAN, 1, 1)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

//Added defaults
int defaults = 0;
    defaults |= android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    defaults |= android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```